# Part of background of VS Code Editor is wrong

Tags: visual-studio-code

Parts of my editor are not the correct colors. I suspect this is some setting to be changed but I am not sure which one. Right now the areas that are the wrong color are parts of the editor background as seen in the first image and the terminal background as seen in the second image. I noticed that the color is the same as the selected line on 6 so that may be related. I have tried disabling the extension, Atom Pro Dark, and reinstalling but the problem persists. If I log in vscode from a browser then it is no longer an issue.[image][image]

Comment: Closing as a duplicate.

Comment: @JumperBot_: Specific questions related to developer tools _are_ generally considered on topic, even if they’re not about programming itself.